# Spring boot - some POST requests serious delayed

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot (embedded tomcat) 1.5.6 + hibernate with Thymeleaf 3 and from time to time i have serious delay in response from POST requests. When i try to submit an empty form the validation for these form takes sometimes 9 seconds. 
There is no info for anything strange in my logs, even GC is not running at this time when this occur.
I can't figure out from where comes this delay. Every suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: [Switch on Hibernate logging](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-logging-guide/) - you might be pulling data from DB to perform validation which might be taking long (as in the query) or blocking.

Enabling logging you'd be able to investigate a bit better:

From the above linked article this is how to switch on logging the SQL queries along with their parameters in Log4J:

```
# SQL statements and parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```